# A simple javascript plugin architecture

Tags: javascript

I've implemented the following code which allows me to bolt modules of code on to my core library via the prototype chain. It's quite prescriptive so any user creating a module has to create an init method and also has to define a queue method:

(working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wG9Pv/)

```
//Constructor
test = function() {
    this.tester = 'The instance was successfully created';
};

//A core method
test.prototype.amethod = function() {

};

//Extend method which facilitates the module system
test.extend = function(name,plugin) {
    test.prototype[name] = plugin.init;
    //later do something with the queue method that's been fed in via the 'plugin' object
};

//Add a module
test.extend('method1', { 

    init: function(val) {
        console.log(this.tester);
    },

    queue: function() {

    },

    render: function() {

    }    
});

//add another module
test.extend('method2',{ 

    init: function() {
        console.log('Init of the plugin has been fired');
    },

    draw : function() {}
});

var test = new test();
test.method1('boom!');
test.method2();
```

Now this all works well but is this a good way of achieving it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me,

I would consider making extend a property of prototype though.

For nitpickings, I think

```
function Test() {
    this.tester = 'The instance was successfully created';
};
```

is preferred to

```
test = function() {
    this.tester = 'The instance was successfully created';
};
```

This ways developers will know to use `new` when using test.
Please read [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript) for the cons of using the `new` keyword.

You probably want to store the entire plugin object provided to `extend`, not just keep `init`.

You probably want to throw an exception if the `plugin` does not have an `init`  property.

I am not sure if you realize that `method1` and `method2` are at the end of the script also "core methods"?